# Angular JS - Passing Firebase data from Service to Controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I am trying to pass my Firebase data from a Service to Controller but getting an error: TypeError: *MeetingNamesService.myCalTimes is not a function*.

**Service:**

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('MeetingNamesService', [function($firebaseArray){

    var myCalTimes = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com");

    myCalTimes.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var calTimes = snapshot.val();
        return $firebaseArray(calTimes);        

    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("Data failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
}])
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('monthsCtrl', function($scope, MeetingNamesService, $ionicLoading) {

    $scope.times = MeetingNamesService.myCalTimes();
    $scope.times = calTimes;    
    console.log($scope.times);
})
```

Any idea why it's not recognising *myCalTimes* as a function? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the services? What's the meaning of `myCalTimes`?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve data from the Firebase database, myCalTimes is reference to this data. I tried to follow these guides:  [https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-start] and [https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html#section-saving-data]

Comment: If `myCalTimes` is a reference to this data, then it wouldn't be a function, right?  Can you explain `myCalTimes.on("value", ...)` do? I think you might confuse about `myCalTimes` and `calTimes` .

Comment: This `myCalTimes.on("value", ...)` Attaches an asynchronous callback to read the data at my reference i.e. `var myCalTimes = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com");` I'm following the example from: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the service after you fetch the data:

```
angular.module('app.services', ['firebase'])

.factory('MeetingNamesService', ['$firebaseArray', function($firebaseArray){
  var myCalTimes = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com");
  return {
    getCalTimes: getCalTimes
  }
  function getCalTimes() {
      return $firebaseArray(mycalTimes);        
  }
}]);
```

You controller should call the function like following:

```
.controller('monthsCtrl', function($scope, MeetingNamesService, $ionicLoading) {
  $scope.times = MeetingNamesService.getCalTimes();
  console.log($scope.times);
});
```

Comment: I see what you mean about returning the service after fetching the data. I tried your code and got this error: `TypeError: MeetingNamesService.getCalTimes is not a function`.

Comment: In this case, I need to you to provide an plunker or JsFidder to help you.

Comment: I've never used these services before but gone with Plunker...the link is: https://plnkr.co/edit/MA3XEKrc2PTNAMMLqnO0?p=info

Comment: I will take a look now. Can you explain why you need the `on(...)` function?

Comment: I'm new to Firebase so I followed the recommended method for retrieving data from their tutorial i.e. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: If I don't need it then thats fine with me. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100513/discussion-between-shaohao-lin-and-greendome).

Comment: Yes. The idea is to use the Service to retrieve the data then use it in different controllers to access the necessary data I need. But at the moment  I can't retrieve it at all. It works fine if I only the controller not a service but it gets messy passing data around controllers/views etc and not its the recommended approach by ionic.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('MeetingNamesService', ['$firebaseArray', function($firebaseArray){
    // this instead of var
    this.myCalTimes = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com");

    this.myCalTimes.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var calTimes = snapshot.val();
        return $firebaseArray(calTimes);        

    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("Data failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
}])
```

Comment: Tried the above but still getting the same error message. Is the Controller code okay?

Comment: i edit the answer ( add `['$firebaseArray',` ). the controller seem ok for me.

Comment: @Alainlb - Wondering if you have any other suggestions I can try? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let the function in the factory take a callback as argument like this:

```
function foo(callback) {
            fbRef.on('value', function (dataSnapshot) {
                        callback(dataSnapshot.val());
                    });
        }
```

And use it like this:

```
service.foo(setFoo);
setFoo = function(data) {
// Use data here
}
```

the .on() function returns a promise and not a function :)

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean as I'm a newbie to angularjs. Are you able give an example using the code I provided above, it is likely to make for sense to me. Thank you.

Comment: I couldn't get the synchronization to work, so i ended up putting the data-logik in my controller :/. I'll come back when i find a better solution.